# Как сменить стандартную программу для запуска файлов с типом .pyw? python3.x

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: прогр]

Мне нужно сменить программу которая будет запускать .pyw с *WordPad* на *Python* или лучше на *Sublime Text 3*.
Пожалуйста помогите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ПКМ на файле `.pyw` -> "Открыть с помощью" -> Отметить галочкой "Всегда использовать это приложения для открытия .pyw файлов" -> "Ещё приложения" -> "Найти другое приложение на этом компьютере" -> выбрать exe-шник нужной программы.